# Issue with change_view save redirect

Tags: django, redirect, django-admin, save

I am attempting to change the redirected for the django admin save button. What I pasted below works on saving an already existing entry (updating) but not on saving a new one. Any thoughts?

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
    result = super(TodoAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, extra_context)
        if not request.POST.has_key('_addanother') and not request.POST.has_key('_continue'):
            result['Location'] = "/"
    return result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to modify [`add_view`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.add_view) the same way you did `change_view`, unless i am not understanding the question correctly.